# Pass StringIO output as argument for os.path like object in subprocess popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, sqlcmd, stringio

I am trying to execute sql code in sqlcmd through subprocess. The "-i" option of sqlcmd expects a file. I am converting the sql code into file stream with StringIO and passing it as a argument to popen, but it fails

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
from io import StringIO
sql="select @@version" ## huge sql
["sqlcmd","-s","sql_SERVER","-i","StringIO(sql)"]
p = Popen(argv, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

output, errors = p.communicate()
```

I get the below error

```
sshProcess = subprocess.Popen(argv,  shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True,bufsize=-1,encoding='latin1')
File "/home/mafiree/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "/home/mafiree/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1637, in _execute_child
self.pid = _posixsubprocess.fork_exec(
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.StringIO
```

Comment: You can't pass a `StringIO` object to `Popen`. I'm not sure why you expect that to work, in any case it seems to require a *file path*.

Comment: Can `sqlcmd` read from standard input? If yes, you can use `stdin=` parameter of `Popen()`

Comment: It seems you can pass a query using the `-Q` option, so you could do `[..., "-Q", "select blah blah bla"]` but as a string object not a `StringIO` object.

Comment: Yes I did use "-Q" before going for "-i". "-Q" option has a limit for the query length

Comment: @AndrejKesely sqlcmd accepts standard input in windows, but fails in linux